# Not able to put values in HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-adapter

I have a HashMap in Adapter in which I want to store a string and a double. I am getting the two values from my model and they are working fine as when I am logging it, it's correct. But I am not able to put those values in the HashMap, every time it's returning null.

```
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("DishName", String.valueOf(dishDetailsModel.getDishName()));          //working fine
                Log.i("Price", String.valueOf(dishDetailsModel.getPrice()));                //working fine
                String dishName = String.valueOf(dishDetailsModel.getDishName());
                Double price = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(dishDetailsModel.getPrice()));
                mOrderDetails.put(dishName, price);                                              //not working
            }
        });

        mOrderDetails.put("Pizza", 45.0);                                                        //working fine

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String details = gson.toJson(mOrderDetails);
        Intent intent= new Intent("OrderDetails");
        Log.i("details", details);                                                          //only pizza is there
        intent.putExtra("CartDetails", details);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Have you initialize your Hashmap by like -> HashMap<String,Double> mOrderDetails = new HashMap<String,Double>()

Comment: Yes, it's like that only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem won't be with the inserting, it will be with understanding of events and when they fire.

The code in onclick event will run, well, on click event, but the rest of the code will run immediately.

Try to debug the app, put breakpoints in various line, try to understand why and when does things happen.

Trust me, try to understand for yourself, it'll be good for Our learning process.

Comment: I understood where I was wrong, but can you help me in one thing, how can I access variable that are declared in onClickListener. Please bear with me I am new in android and java.

Comment: If a variable is declared in click listener, you can not access it from outside. Research about scopes in Java. Just asking but, Is my answer helpful in any manner?

Comment: Yes, it's helpful because of your answer only I was able to know my fault. Thanks man.